# Is it necessary to use strict when using certain es6 methods in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, use-strict

We are having a debate at my work, some people say when using es6 and nodejs, without babel of course, you should always add 'use strict' BECAUSE some es6 methods may not work. I can't find documentation supporting this, is it true?

Comment: Are you asking if strict mode is enabled by default or something because you're using es6? No, it's not.

Comment: answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31685340/17447) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29285330/17447)

Answer (score 2):

Per the spec:

> Module code is always strict mode code.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code