# Difference between es5 and es6 'use strict' feature

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am fairly new to es6. I am trying to migrate the code from es5 to es6. Some of the files(javascript) uses 'use strict'.

I was just confused whether this should be kept as it is  or should it be removed.

What are the implication?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685262/not-recommended-to-use-use-strict-in-es6