# javascript: use strict is unnecessary inside of modules

Tags: javascript

tsling raise an error:

> Line 1:  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules (strict)

this is my code

```
"use strict";

function Foo() {}

Foo.prototype.sayHello= function () {
    console.log("hello!");
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = { 
        Foo: Foo
    };
}
```

how fix this error?

**Side note**

my code is used both `module` and vanilla javascript. I want use `"strict mode"` only for vanilla javascript.

maybe i can use

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    "use strict";
}
```

for enabling `strict mode` only for vanilla javascript?

Comment: try removing `"use strict";`

Comment: Line 1: 'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules strict i think this line answer your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not recommended to use "use strict" in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685262/not-recommended-to-use-use-strict-in-es6)

Answer (score 16):

Remove `'use strict'`. As the error mentions, it's unnecessary. Modules are expected to execute in strict mode. Compilers will add it for you when you export the module into a script for non-module consumption (i.e. UMD/CJS). See `--alwaysStrict` option for TS.

Comment: ok, but my code is used both in module and vanilla javascript

Answer (score 6):

ES6 modules are always in strict mode.