# Is 'use strict' implied when ES modules is used?

Tags: javascript

I was learning JS and came across 'use strict'. Then, here [Should I 'use strict' for every single javascript function I write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301881/should-i-use-strict-for-every-single-javascript-function-i-write) @Bergi says that "you only should put 'use strict' in the module scope - once per file - so that it is inherited by all your functions". Is it true that by "it is inherited by all your functions" means each function in a certain module uses 'use strict' inside of itself?

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code

Comment: any `type="module"` script is automatically in strict-mode, yes.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, so e.g if we have function like  function Addition(){'use strict'}, each function inside es module has use strict in itself. Right?

Comment: If you are using native JavaScript modules, then *all* the code within your modules will be in strict mode by default. If you are using older hand-rolled modularisation patterns, then you will need to declare `'use strict'` at the top of the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it true that by "it is inherited by all your functions" means each function in a certain module uses 'use strict' inside of itself?

A function will run in strict mode if:

(1) The function is inside an ES6 module (these all run in strict mode regardless), or

(2) There is a proper `'use strict'` directive above the function definition, *lexically*.

In addition to a few less common instances, such as inside a `constructor`.

The way `'use strict'` is inherited lexically works the same way variables can be referenced, and how variable scope works - if any outer block of a function is strict, then the inner function is strict as well. So, for example, with the following code:

```
'use strict';
function foo() {
  function bar() {
    function baz() {
    }
  }
}
```

No matter what other code you put inside `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, *all* of those functions, no matter how they're run, will run in strict mode. If one of these function is called from a source which *isn't* running in strict mode, the called function will still run in strict mode. For example:

```html
<script>
'use strict';
function foo() {
  return function bar() {
    return function baz() {
      console.log('baz running. strict:', this === undefined);
    }
  }
}
foo()()();
</script>
<script>
// Non-strict script calling strict function:
foo()()();
</script>
```