# WebStorm Run/Debug configuration: Adding "--use-strict" as Node parameter does nothing

Tags: javascript, webstorm, run-configuration, strict-mode

I am starting to code JavaScript on JetBrains WebStorm, and I am trying to follow a few examples from a book. I am trying to avoid adding `use-strict` at the start of every code file, knowing fully that using this approach should be used [with caution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301881/should-i-use-strict-for-every-single-javascript-function-i-write).

When I use a console with `node --use-strict` (with the flag) and execute the following line:

```
coutner = 1
```

I get the expected error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: coutner is not defined**.

Then I try using the Run/Debug configuration:
First, I define a new Run/Debug configuration that uses the same node as before, with a node parameter `--use-strict`:

[image]

Then I execute a file composed of the above code (with or without adding another line: `console.log(coutner)` after it) using that run configuration, the code executes, and I am not getting the expected error. Why is that?

I've also added the "Non-strict mode used" inspection under *Settings -> Editor -> Inspections*, and I get no warning for the file mentioned above.

In addition, I am using WebStorm on a Windows 11 computer and Ubuntu-22.04 through WSL2. These examples don't work on both Windows and Ubuntu node.js interpreters.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by 'running in console'? What console is meant? I can't find `--use-strict` in the list of Node.js options in https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html

Comment: Ok, seems to be a V8 flag. But it only works in Node REPL, see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30039