# Promise.then execution context when using class methods as callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Why does `Promise.then` passes execution context of `undefined` when using a class method as callback, and `window` when using a "normal function"?

Is the class method detached from its owning object/class? and why `undefined` and not `window`?

```
function normal() {
    console.log('normal function', this);
}
const arrow = () => {
    console.log('arrow function', this);
}

function strictFunction() {
    'use strict';
    console.log('strict function', this);
}

class Foo {
    test() {
        this.method(); // Foo
        Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('inline arrow function', this)); // Foo
        Promise.resolve().then(normal); // window
        Promise.resolve().then(arrow); // window
        Promise.resolve().then(strictFunction); // undefined
        Promise.resolve().then(this.method); // undefined <-- why?
    }

    method() {
        console.log('method', this);
    }
}

const F = new Foo();
F.test();
```

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2027g8k/1))

I would expect the context of `this.method` to be lost but cannot understand why the different behavior between `this.method` and "normal" and arrow functions.

Is there a spec for this behavior? The only reference I found was Promises A+ refering to that *"in strict mode `this` will be `undefined` inside; in sloppy mode, it will be the `global object`."*.

Comment: A class method reference passed as `obj.method` is _always_ detached from `obj` - this isn't Promises specific.

Comment: @Alnitak but why `undefined` and not `window` [as expected (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/9x47jahe/)?

Comment: not sure - perhaps ES6 class methods are implicitly strict?

Comment: [`class` methods are always strict mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29283935/1048572). `then` passes nothing (`undefined`) as context, the rest is just the [usual behavior of the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quote you have there tells you why:

> in strict mode `this` will be undefined inside; in sloppy mode, it will be the global object.

The [ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code) says that:

> All parts of a ClassDeclaration or a ClassExpression are strict mode code

Therefore, because of **strict mode**, `this` within an unbound class method, will be `undefined`.

```js
class A {
  method() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

const a = new A();
a.method(); // A
const unboundMethod = a.method;
unboundMethod(); // undefined
```

This is the same behavior you would get if you passed a normal function with strict mode because `this` binding is `undefined` by default in strict mode, not set to the global object.

The reason `normal` and `arrow` have `this` as `window` is because they are not within the class and thus not wrapped in strict mode.

---

As far as promises and the `then` method, it will just pass `undefined` as `this` but won't override already bound `this`.

If you look at the [PromiseReactionJob](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promisereactionjob) spec:

> The job PromiseReactionJob with parameters reaction and argument applies the appropriate handler to the incoming value, and uses the handler's return value to resolve or reject the derived promise associated with that handle.

```
...
let handlerResult be Call(handler, undefined, «argument»).
```

The second argument to Call is the `this` value, which is set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with Promises, but rather the context in which `this` is called.

**Case 1:**

```
this.method(); // Foo
```

Here `method` is a function defined within the `Foo` class, so `this` is evaluated as the object that triggered the function, which is `this` in `this.method`. Hence - `Foo` is displayed.

**Case 2:**

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('inline arrow function', this)); // Foo
```

Arrow functions are a feature of ES6, whose unique property is that the `this` context in the enclosing context where it is defined. The function was called in a context where `this === Foo` so that's what's displayed.

**Case 3:**

```
Promise.resolve().then(normal); // window
Promise.resolve().then(arrow); // window
```

The arrow function retains its context as the window since it's an arrow function, and the normal function is evaluated without a context, in which `this` is evaluated to window when not in `strict mode`.

**Case 4:**

```
Promise.resolve().then(strictFunction); // undefined
```

Since `strict mode` is requested within the body of this function, which is declared on the window, `this` is evaluated to undefined.

**Case 5:**

```
Promise.resolve().then(this.method); // undefined <-- why?
```

In this [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-directive-prologues-and-the-use-strict-directive), it is defined that all Class code is strict code:

> All parts of a ClassDeclaration or a ClassExpression are strict mode code.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, it is not clear if OP's code is part of a module.

Comment: @nem035 Correct, I had the wrong quote in mind. Edited, thanks.

Comment: "*functions that are defined on the window*" - no, that's not the reason why `normal` gets `window`

Comment: What is the idiomatic to handle this then? I'd like the outer scope of a React class to be accessible in the then of a Promise. I can create const that = this, but wondering if there is something less messy.

Comment: @zero_cool Sounds like you can either use an arrow function in the `promise.then` callback, or create a callback and bind it to `this` in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it helped the simple solution of defining "self".

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public cards: Card[] = [];
  public events: any[] = [];

  constructor(private fbService: FacebookService) {
    this.fbService.loadSdk();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const self = this;

    this.fbService.getEvents().then((json: any) => {
      for (const event of json.data)
      {
        self.cards.push(
          new Card({
            imageUrl: 'assets/ny.jpg',
            id: event.id,
            name: event.name
          }),
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**fb.service.ts**

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


declare var window: any;
declare var FB: any;

@Injectable()
export class FacebookService {
  events: any[];

  public ready = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  }

  public loadSdk() {
    this.loadAsync(() => { });
  }


  public loadAsync(callback: () => void) {
    window.fbAsyncInit = () => this.zone.run(callback);
    // Load the Facebook SDK asynchronously
    const s = 'script';
    const id = 'facebook-jssdk';
    const fjs = document.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    // tslint:disable-next-line:curly
    if (document.getElementById(id)) return;

    const js = document.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }

  public getEvents(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      FB.init({
        appId: 'app_id',
        xfbml: true,
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        version: 'v2.10'
      });

      FB.api(
        '/salsaparty.bg/events',
        'GET',
        {
          access_token: 'acess_token'
        },
        function (response) {
          resolve(response);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `this.method` is undefined is because when you use it like that, you are actually just taking the function, devoid of context, as the callback. So, when it's run, it doesn't know this.

If you want to maintain context, use the `bind` function.

```
Promise.resolve().then(this.method.bind(this))
```

Bind will bind the context to the method. It's essentially equivalent to this:

```
Promise.resolve().then(((self) => () => self.method())(this))
```

which is a wrapper to map the context to a variable in a scope.

With a class method, when you get it as a variable, it's essentially no difference from a variable containing a reference to a function.

For example:

```
const a = () => {};

class Foo {
    a() {}
}
const foo = new Foo();

console.log(a); // just a function
console.log(foo.a) // just a function
console.log(foo.a()) // a function called with a context of foo
```

When you call a method on an object, like `foo.a()` it's essentially the same as doing `foo.a.call(foo)`, where you set the context of `a` to foo. When you just take `foo.a` and separate it from `foo`, it's the same as doing `foo.a.call(window)` (or `global` in Node).

Here is some code that illustrates the differences. You can also see how if you `bind` it, it'll maintain context.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.b = this.b.bind(this);
  }
  
  a () {
    return this;
  }
  
  b () {
    return this;
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
const a = foo.a;
const b = foo.b;
const bound = foo.a.bind(foo);

console.log('A', foo.a().constructor.name);
console.log('A', a());
console.log('A', a.apply(foo).constructor.name);
console.log('A', bound().constructor.name);

console.log('B', foo.b().constructor.name);
console.log('B', b().constructor.name);
```

Comment: Can you explain more _"devoid of context"_? why is this different from a named function?