# Variable not defined inside ES6 class without 'let' or 'var'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When I use the ES6 class syntax, a variable inside a method declared without 'let' or 'var' is undefined. However, when using the regular object syntax, it is defined.

To illustrate the problem, I run the following code on Node v7.5.0:

```
class ES6Foo {

   bar() {  

       var i = 5446;
       console.log("i = " + i);

       let j = 5446;
       console.log("j = " + j);

       k = 5446;
       console.log("k = " + k);

    }
}

foo = new ES6Foo();
foo.bar();
```

produces the output:

```
i = 5446
j = 5446
.../ES6Foo.js:10
    k = 5446;
      ^
ReferenceError: k is not defined
at ES6Foo.bar
```

Not using the class syntax solves this problem:

```
var OldFoo = function() {}

OldFoo.prototype.bar = function() {

   var i = 5446;
   console.log("i = " + i);

   let j = 5446;
   console.log("j = " + j);

   k = 5446;
   console.log("k = " + k);

}

foo = new OldFoo();
foo.bar();
```

produces:

```
i = 5446
j = 5446
k = 5446
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: The code in a `class` is executed using strict mode. This forbids implicit globals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Strict_mode

Comment: I'd argue that your second code example doesn't solve a problem, but rather allows a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I use the ES6 class syntax, a variable inside a method declared without 'let' or 'var' is undefined.

Actually, it's *undeclared*. That's why you get an exception.

> However, when using the regular object syntax, it is defined.

That's because [ES6 class methods automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29283935/1048572) run in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), your regular object syntax does only run in sloppy mode. (It should not! `"use strict"` mode everywhere!)
Assigning to an undeclared identifier [will implicitly create a global variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), a thing which you'll definitely want to avoid.

> Not using the class syntax solves this problem

No, the problem is *solved* by properly declaring the variable.

Comment: Thanks! Is it a good rule of thumb to always declare variables with a keyword, even though you can get away with it outside of strict mode? Is there ever a situation where you would want to implicitly create a global variable?

Comment: @BrianZanti *"Is there ever a situation where you would want to implicitly create a global variable?"* – No. Such implicit behaviour is a terrible trap to consciously leave in your code base. Pretty much every linter will warn of their existence, and I would immediately reject the offensive lines in code review.