# Object.defineProperty sometimes throws

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, defineproperty

I am playing with ES6 classes and non-writable properties.  As an example, I have the following code.  I am running it under node version v9.9.0.

```js
  Crash = class Crash {
    constructor() {
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'test', {
        enumerable: true,
        value: 100
      });
    }

    setTest(val) {
      this.test = val;
    }

  };

  c = new Crash;
  c.test = 10;    // happens silently
  console.log(c); // displays Crash { test: 100 }
                  // so it didn't change
  c.setTest(20);  // Throws a typeError
  
  // TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'test' of object '#<Crash>'
```

So it seems that if a read-only instance property is set from outside the instance, the assignment is ignored; if set from inside the instance, it's a TypeError.

Is this expected behaviour?  I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: [(MDN) `Object.define Property()` -> Writable attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Writable_attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected behaviour? I can't find it documented anywher

Yes, in non strict mode

**Read this:** [Modifying a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property)

In strict mode the error will be thrown:

```js
'use strict'; // <------- Strict mode

class Crash {
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'test', {
      enumerable: true,
      value: 100
    });
  }

  setTest(val) {
    this.test = val;
  }
};

var c = new Crash;
c.test = 10; // happens silently
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that [your `class` method is in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29283935/1048572), while the rest of your code is implicitly sloppy. Try

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  const c = new Crash;
//^^^^^ needs declaration for not failing here alredy
  c.test = 10;    // Throws a TypeError as expected
  console.log(c);
}());
```