# Google Closure Compiler addes "use strict" to result file when --language_out is set to ECMASCRIPT_2015

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Google Closure Compiler addes "use strict" to result file when --language_out is set to ECMASCRIPT_2015

For some unknown reason, when setting the "--language_out ECMASCRIPT_2015" param, the program forces the use of strict mode and adds “use strict” at the beginning of the result file.

Neither "--jscomp_off es5Strict" no any undocumented params help. It looks like GCC in ECMASCRIPT_2015-compatible mode uses "strict mode" as default.

Anybody knows how to turn it off?

I use the last GCC version for java via bat-file command:

```
java -jar %USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Portable\ClosureCompiler\cc.jar --js %1.%2 --js_output_file %1.min.%2 --language_in ECMASCRIPT_2015 --language_out ECMASCRIPT_2015 --jscomp_off es5Strict
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not related to `--language_in ECMASCRIPT_2015` rather? Notice that [ES6 module code is always strict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29285330/1048572).

Comment: May be it causes too. I need to explain: I began to use es6 structures in my code and GCC started to add to minified files $jscomp warning system code. Twice it caused me bugs in tested before code - only in minificated files. I suppose there should not be need testing both original and minified code separately... The "--jscomp_off es5Strict", the "--jscomp_off=*" don't work to me. Then I tried to turn on es6 mode - and faced to described problem that it suggests only strict mode in output file. I did not see that es6 requires mode to be strict - it  is only an option...

Comment: In ES6 *modules*, it is enforced. In normal scripts, it's still opt-in for backward compat. Do you use `import` and `export` syntax? Then you use strict mode.

Comment: Btw, what's the problem with using it? What sloppy mode features do you need?

Comment: switched to use terser ((

Answer (score 3):

There is now an option for this, `--emit_use_strict=false`

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing and working with `Google Closure Compiler`, you can ***disable*** *strict mode* with the following code:

```
CompilerOptions compilerOptions = new CompilerOptions();
compilerOptions.setEmitUseStrict(false);

List<SourceFile> externs = CommandLineRunner.getDefaultExterns();
compiler.compile(externs, Lists.newArrayList(input), compilerOptions);
```