# Why does JS throw TypeError for Class Instances but doesn't do anything in case of Object Literals when tried to override Non-writable Data Property?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, properties, prototype

### Foreword

Going through MDN Docs, I found 2 interesting points about *object property inheritance* in JS.
The article on [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#inheritance_of_properties) points out that

> Unlike accessor properties, data properties are always set on the object itself, not on a prototype. However, if a non-writable data property is inherited, it is still prevented from being modified on the object.

To my understanding, it means that any accessor property or non-writable data property of an object cannot be overridden by it's child object unless such a property is defined on the child object explicitly using Object.defineProperty() static method.

Also, there's this peculiar aspect of [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#setting_super.prop_sets_the_property_on_this_instead) which sets a property on the current `this` object as stated as follows:

> Setting properties of `super`, such as `super.x = 1`, behaves like `Reflect.set(Object.getPrototypeOf(objectLiteral), "x", 1, this)`. This is one of the cases where understanding super as simply "reference of the prototype object" falls short, because it actually sets the property on `this` instead.

But using `super` also doesn't allow overriding of accessor or non-writable data property as highlighted below:

> However, `super.x = 1` still consults the property descriptor of the prototype object, which means you cannot rewrite non-writable properties, and setters will be invoked.

---

### The Question

Consider the following piece of code:

```js
class A {
    get ap() { return this.x;}
    set ap(arg) { this.x = arg; }
}
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'dp', {writable: true, value: 'writable'});
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'nwdp', {writable: false, value: 'locked'});

class B extends A {
    method() {
        super.dp = 200; // Override it
        super.ap = 'bird';  // Doesn't override it; Invokes setter, ap at A.prototype
        super.nwdp = 'unlocked';  // Doesn't override it; Throws TypeError
    }
}

b = new B()
```

When called `b.method()`, it sets `dp` and `x` on the instance, `b` (checked using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)`) but will throw `TypeError`.

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'nwdp' of object '#B'
```

Similarly, when `super.prop = <any_value>` is used in an object literal, it functions the same way but it doesn't throw any error.

```js
let obj1 = {
    dp: 'writable',

    get ap() { return this.x; },
    set ap(arg) { this.x = arg; }
};
Object.defineProperty(obj1, 'nwdp', {writable: false, value: 'locked'});

let obj2 = {
    method() {
        super.dp = 200; // Overrides it
        super.ap = 'bird'; // Doesn't override it; Invokes setter, ap at obj1

        // Doesn't override it; But doesn't throw any kind of error as if it doesn't do anything
        super.nwdp = 'unlocked';
        }
};
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj2, obj1);
obj2.method();
```

Using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2)` shows properties `dp`, `x` and `method` on the object, `obj2`.

So, the question actually is *why does JS behave like this?*
In both the scenarios, it behaves exactly the same except when it is about overriding a non-writable data property on the child object using `super.prop = <any_value>`, it throws `TypeError` for properties meant to be defined for a *class instance* whereas it  seems like it ignores the same statement in case of *object literals*.

Is this intentional? If so, what's the reason behind it? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Assigning to a child object property **never** changes the property on an object up the prototype chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parts of `class` bodies are "strict" mode code, and that's when you get that Type Error. Your second example is not "strict".  You can make it so if you want, and then you'll get the error.

```
"use strict"; // has to be start of script file or function

let obj1 = {
    dp: 'writable',

    get ap() { return this.x; },
    set ap(arg) { this.x = arg; }
};
Object.defineProperty(obj1, 'nwdp', {writable: false, value: 'locked'});

let obj2 = {
    method() {
        super.dp = 200; // Overrides it
        super.ap = 'bird'; // Doesn't override it; Invokes setter, ap at obj1

        // Doesn't override it; But doesn't throw any kind of error as if it doesn't do anything
        super.nwdp = 'unlocked';
        }
};
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj2, obj1);
obj2.method();
```

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is not between `class` methods and object literal methods but rather between strict mode and sloppy mode. That assignments to non-writable properties are silently ignored is a legacy behaviour, it should not happen in modern code that does [`"use strict"` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Of course, [everything in ES6 `class` definitions is strict by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29283935/1048572), whereas normal top-level code is sloppy by default for compatibility reasons. You should use ES6 modules, or always begin your scripts with  the `"use strict";` directive.